# Unable to start the Coap server in a Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, iot, coap

I am trying to add a Coap server through Eclipse Californium in a Java Spring boot-based application. Below are the codes.

```
import org.eclipse.californium.core.CoapServer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class CoapServerConfiguration {

     @Bean
    public CoapServer coapServer() {
         int portNumber = 9995;
         CoapServer coapServer= null;
            try {
             coapServer = new CoapServer(portNumber);
             coapServer.add();
            }catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        // Add your CoAP resources here
        // server.add(new YourCoapResource());

      //  System.out.println("Coap server started");
        return coapServer;
    }
}
```

However, when I start the application, I get the following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Configuration contains no definitions!
    at org.eclipse.californium.elements.config.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:802)
    at org.eclipse.californium.elements.config.Configuration.load(Configuration.java:772)
    at org.eclipse.californium.elements.config.Configuration.load(Configuration.java:738)
    at org.eclipse.californium.elements.config.Configuration.createWithFile(Configuration.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.californium.elements.config.Configuration.createStandardWithFile(Configuration.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.californium.elements.config.Configuration.getStandard(Configuration.java:458)
    at org.eclipse.californium.core.CoapServer.<init>(CoapServer.java:184)
    at com.dropbydrop.smartmeter.CoapServerConfiguration.coapServer(CoapServerConfiguration.java:16)
```

I have added the following dependencies also,in this application.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.californium</groupId>
    <artifactId>californium-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.0</version>
</dependency>

   
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.californium/element-connector -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.californium</groupId>
    <artifactId>element-connector</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.36</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.californium/californium-legal -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.californium</groupId>
    <artifactId>californium-legal</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.0</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It looks like it is loading the default configuration as expected e.g Configuration.getStandard().  But that it is trying to create something from a file.  Maybe a Californium.properties is required even if using default config?  Idk,  I would just look at the org.eclipse.californium.elements.config.Configuration.java class and see what it is trying to do.  Is it trying to load a config file? Which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with Californium 3.0, the configuration uses modules. Before using the configuration, the required modules must be registered. See [Config.register()](https://github.com/eclipse-californium/californium/blob/main/element-connector/src/main/java/org/eclipse/californium/elements/config/Configuration.java#L110-L118)

Comment: Yes, with Config.register(), it is working.